# Why doesn't document.forms return all forms in firebug console?

Tags: javascript, firebug

I do a lot of my work from Chrome's developer tools console and firebug console in Firefox.  In both cases when I run `document.forms` or `$('form')` with jQuery enabled, it doesn't return all the forms on the page.  Why is this?  How can I get it to return all forms on the page?

Example page:
http://www.newcartestdrive.com/ (doesn't include "Select A Make/Model" form)

Comment: Which ones does it return, and which ones does it not?

Comment: It's included for me in `document.forms` (third form in the array) on Chrome latest version. Same with `$('form')`, just checked.

Comment: It doesn't include the form with id "pass".  Note that the site is just an example, I need a general solution for the problem.

Comment: console.log(document.forms); // <form name="pass".. is in there

Comment: @draevor, Hmmmm, yeah I get it on firefox.  Try here: http://www.newcartestdrive.com/.  I can't get the form which has the "Select A Make", "Select A Model" dropdowns.

Comment: There's a screen of my console: http://ScrnSht.com/aoucpc

Comment: @Muhd Yes, but there it's normal - that form is loaded in an iframe, it's another document and you cannot access it.

Comment: @Muhd The newcartestdrive form is in an iframe and therefore would not be part of the `document`

Comment: ah ok didn't notice.  Here's a screenshot of the other page: http://ScrnSht.com/llfswb -- I'll take your word for it that it works in newest Chrome.  Maybe it's just an intermittent bug.

Comment: It's there bro, it's on the right side of that list:) http://ScrnSht.com/molovn

Comment: @AlienWebguy, Didn't see it there! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`document.forms` will contain all forms declared inside the current document. Any forms included in an iframe will not be part of the document, but will be part of that iFrame's document.

Comment: Thanks. I can't believe I didn't notice the iframe before.